# How to Filter in GridView from 2 table relation

Tags: yii2

need help here..
iam trying gridview from 2 table relation. i have succes retrieving the data from first table into gridview but become no filter. so far this is what iam doing

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Smwp::find()                          
           ->joinWith('mfwpData');

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);


    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'id_sm_wp' => $this->id_sm_wp,
        'tgl_surat' => $this->tgl_surat,
        'tgl_terima' => $this->tgl_terima,
        'tgl_cetak' => $this->tgl_cetak,
        'no_agenda' => $this->no_agenda,
        'index_hal' => $this->index_hal,
        'index_cetak' => $this->index_cetak,

    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'no_surat', $this->no_surat])            
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'judul_hal', $this->judul_hal])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'lokasi_scan', $this->lokasi_scan])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'ket_dispo', $this->ket_dispo])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'mfwpData.npwp', $this->id_mfwp])                                     
        ;

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

and here is rules function. iam inserting id_mfwp into safe part

```
    public function rules()
    {
    return [
        [['id', 'id_sm_wp', 'no_agenda', 'index_hal', 'index_cetak'], 
        'integer'],
        [['tgl_surat', 'tgl_terima', 'tgl_cetak', 'no_surat', 'judul_hal', 
        'lokasi_scan', 'ket_dispo', 'íd_mfwp'], 'safe'],
    ];
    }
```

and here is my relation in model

```
    public function getMfwpData()
   {
     return $this->hasOne(Mfwp::className(), ['id' => 'id_sm_wp']);
   }


   public function getNamaUser()
   {
     return $this->hasOne(Mfwp::className(), ['id' => 'id_sm_wp'])- 
     >with(['pejabat']);
   }
```

and here is code in my index :

```
         ['attribute'=>'id_mfwp',
         'label'=>'NPWP',
         'format'=>'raw',
         'value'=>'mfwpData.npwp'],

         ['attribute'=>'id_mfwp',
         'label'=>'Nama Wajib Pajak',
         'format'=>'raw',
          'value'=>'mfwpData.nama_wp'],

         ['attribute'=>'id_mfwp',
         'label'=>'Nama AR',
         'format'=>'raw',
         'value'=>'namaUser.pejabat.nama'],
```

i am still cannot show filter in gridview..thank for helping

Comment: so your question is how to sort the gridview with relation?

Comment: and you are using the same attribute for the all 3 columns in gridview which isnt correct

Comment: see this article and adjust accordingly https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview

Comment: What a great search.. Now i know you are master in yii2.. Why i cant search this page for last 6 hour..?thx my bro.. May allah swt gives you mercy and baroka..please help me in my next question..LoL